# Button Render depending on a boolean value

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton, rendered, boolean

I have the following piece of code

```
function toggleButton(box, id1, id2) {
var elm1 = document.getElementById(id1);
var elm2 = document.getElementById(id2);
if(box.checked){
elm1.style.display = "";
elm2.style.display = "";
} else {
elm1.style.display = "none";
elm2.style.display = "none";
}
}
<td width="10%"/>
<td width="80%"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-mini-0" id="checkbox-mini-0" data-mini="true" onclick="javascript: toggleButton(this,'j_id0:LandingForm:inviteRegisterButton','j_id0:LandingForm:inviteLoginButton');"></input>&nbsp;<b>Yes, I have read the provisions document and agree with the conditions</b></td>
<td></td>
<apex:commandButton id="inviteRegisterButton" value="Register and Accept" style="display:none;width:125px;height:25px;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;background-color:#f9f9f9;border-radius:6px;" 
   action="{!AppPA}" rendered="!{!hasuser}"/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<apex:commandButton id="inviteLoginButton" value="Login and Accept" style="display:none;width:125px;height:25px;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;background-color:#f9f9f9;border-radius:6px;" 
   action="{!AppPB}" rendered="{!hasuser}"/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

hasuser is a variable of the controller.

Here one of the two buttons gets displayed depending on whether the value of hasuser is true or false.

1. If hasuser is true **Register and Accept** gets displayed
2. If hasuser is false Login and Accept gets diplayed. This code doesn't seem to be working. can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

This where the value of hasuser is being set to true or false. This is the constructor of the controller class

```
public LandingPageController(){

UserId= ApexPages.currentpage().getParameters().get('UserId');
hasuser=false;
        System.debug('hasusercheck 1 '+hasuser);
        if(UserId!=null){
            hasuser=true;
            System.debug('hasusercheck 2 '+hasuser);
         }
        System.debug('hasusercheck 3 '+hasuser);        
    }
```

Comment: How is it not working? Do both buttons display?

Comment: when hasuser is false register and accept gets displayed. When hasuuser is true none of the buttons gets displayed @AntonioManente

Answer (score 4):

Your first condition is wrong if you are doing **NOT** in your condition correct syntax is

```
rendered="{!!hasuser}"
```

Comment: I have tried it too...its not working either @himanshu

Comment: when you make that false? because on page load it can be either true or false

Comment: I use this syntax: {!hasuser = false}

Comment: what is the data type of hasUser ?

Comment: @Rimii, I agree with Himanshu, alternate syntax is `rendered="{!NOT(hasUser)}`" but this shouldn't matter; is the visibility part of an Ajax refresh?

Comment: No its not a part of ajax refresh. When hasuser is true the register and accept gets diplayed. When hasuser is false , none of the buttons gets displayed . I tried all the ways described above @crop1645

Comment: Can you post your code where you make that true or false

Comment: This where the value of hasuser is being set to true or false. This is the constructor of the controller class


public LandingPageController(){

UserId= ApexPages.currentpage().getParameters().get('UserId');
hasuser=false;
        System.debug('hasusercheck 1 '+hasuser);
        if(UserId!=null){
            hasuser=true;
            System.debug('hasusercheck 2 '+hasuser);
         }
        System.debug('hasusercheck 3 '+hasuser);        
    }

Comment: are you passing UserId in url ?

Comment: Yes I am passing the userid in the url. I checked that as well. The debug log is populating it correctly

Comment: i am expecting that you see Login and Accept button in that case ?

Comment: when hasuser is false register and accept gets displayed. When hasuser is true none of the buttons gets displayed. There is a javascript function as well where the Ids of both the buttons is being passed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33560/discussion-between-himanshu-and-rimii).